# Add Script To All Pages On Click Of An Image

Tags: wordpress, zendesk

I created a function (myFunction88) that holds the zen desk chat widget script that is only activated on click of an image in the bottom right corner of a staging site.

http://allcal.staging.wpengine.com/

The purpose is to not load the chat script at all unless someone clicks to start a chat. Increase my site's load speed and not load the chat script on every page when most users don't use it.

It works great. Image in the corner. Click on image, loads the chat.

***My Question is how can I load the script on every page when the image is clicked so the chat will follow the user? Currently the chat only works on the page it clicked on so if you go to a new page, have to start a new chat. Is there a way to onclick of the image, load "myFunction88" output script to every page for that user so the chat is activated on all pages they visit?

JS:

```
function myFunction88() {
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?[My ZenDeskChatNumber]";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");

});}
```

In Function.php:

```
add_action ( 'wp_footer', 'hook_infooter' );

function hook_infooter() {

echo '<<div class="chatimagediv"><img id="chatimageid" 
class="chatimage2" src="https://beachcandyswimwear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Screen-Shot-2018-11-07-at-8.18.03-AM.png" width=240 
onclick="myFunction88(); toggleClick4();"></div>>';

}
```

Comment: may be you can set and get cookies with some expiry time? so you can include the js on click on if cookie is set.

Comment: What would I need to add to the code above?

Comment: I'm on mobile now so can't code but you can check my recent commit in on one of my frnds repo for same purpose but it was for color toggle. [check code here](https://github.com/harsh98trivedi/harsh98trivedi.github.io/commit/54431afbfad85e7c77acfcd4975784544b4a05c1) instead of colorCheck you can add like chatCheck true or false in your function88